# How do I download an image and convert to base64 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can I post an Image to another page without downloading it?
(convert to base64 and post)

```
function run(){
  const url = 'http://g1.gangsters.pl/php/ks_sa_100.php?co=61';
  const body = new FormData()
  body.append('blokada', true)
  body.append('y', Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 100 + 1)) + 100)

  fetch(url, { method: 'POST', body })
}

setInterval(() => {
  console.log('Robbing....')
  run()
}, 1700)
```

How do I add something to download this image, http://g1.gangsters.pl/php/sec_token.php?type=sa a then convert it to a base64 string?

Comment: Just FYI, you *have* to download it to convert it, but you don't need to see it being downloaded or saved locally.

Comment: Why would you ever do that? Can't you setup your server to fetch from the URI directly? I mean, you are going to download the full file from client, then upload it as a 130% bigger dataURI? Makes no sense. And this is all assuming that the original server allows you to fetch this resource from cross-origin page (which is not that common).

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right

- first get an image into base64,
- send afterwards that base64 within a `body` of a POST request

You could first wait (using Promise) that a FileReader reads the imageData. `.then` pass the base64 to your next (post) function:

```
const toDataURL = (url) => fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => new Promise((res, err) => {
    const FR = new FileReader();
    FR.onloadend = () => res(FR.result);
    FR.readAsDataURL(blob);
    FR.onerror = err;
  }));

const toSecToken = toDataURL('http://g1.gangsters.pl/php/sec_token.php?type=sa')
  .then(base64 => {
    const body = new FormData();
    body.append('base64', base64);
    body.append('blokada', true);
    body.append('y', Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 100 + 1)) + 100);
    return fetch('http://g1.gangsters.pl/php/ks_sa_100.php?co=61', { method:'POST', body });
  });

toSecToken.then(res => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

As noted by others, this should be better handled on the server side. Sending an image back and forth (+ the 1/4 of added weight since the base64 encoding - and a server that allows CORS...) seems like an unnecessary overhead.
So the `sec_token.php` could be extended to handle the image forwarding to `ks_sa_100.php` (+ the necessary query params like `co=61` or whatever is needed)

```
# ks_sa_100.php?co=61

$img = file_get_contents('http://g1.gangsters.pl/php/sec_token.php?type=sa');  
$base64 = base64_encode($img); // if you really need that base64 data string
```

Resources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: This assumes that the resource is served from a server that do allow cross-origin requests.

Comment: index.php?id=19:1 Cross-origin plugin content from  must have a visible size larger than 400 x 300 pixels, or it will be blocked. Invisible content is always blocked. how can I do this another way?

Comment: @IfaBoss Try to add on top of your PHP file `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`